# Convert from boost time to std::chrono for C++11

Tags: c++11, boost, c++-chrono

I would like to replace some boost time lines with std::chrono.

*`boost::posix_time::ptime myTime( boost::gregorian::date(1960, 1, 1))`
As far as I know, Gregorian time is available on C++20. So is there a way to work around this for C++11?

*`boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()`
and
`boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()`
I guess I could replace this with `high_resolution_clock`. But how can I get the `local_time()` and `universal_time()` equivalents for `std`?

*`boost::posix_time::time_duration`

*`boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time()`

**EDIT:**
After reviewing Howaard's question here are some findings:

1. I converted `boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time()` to `auto const timeout = std::chrono::system_clock::now()`
   However this gives me the following errors:

   /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:155:31: error: ‘const struct std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >’ has no member named ‘is_pos_infinity’
   if (`wait_duration.is_pos_infinity()`)

   /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:160:31: error: ‘const struct std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >’ has no member named ‘is_special’
   if (`wait_duration.is_special()`)

/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:164:50: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘boost::system_time’ {aka ‘boost::posix_time::ptime’} and ‘const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long int, std::ratio<1, 1000000000> > >’)
return timed_wait(m,`get_system_time()+wait_duration`);

2. About the conversion from `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()` to `std::chrono::system_clock`... Do i have to use a method contained in `system_clock()`?

---

3. Isn't there any way (even hacky way) to convert these two lines:

   boost::posix_time::ptime time_t_epoch(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1))

   ```
    boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()
   ```

to C++11 std::chrono?

Answer (score 1):

For C++11, I have written a [C++20 chrono preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which is open source.  The library is divided roughly in two:

1. Deals with UTC and calendars.
2. Deals with time zones.

The first part is header-only and lives in `"date/date.h"`.  The second part lives in `"date/tz.h"` and has an associated source that must be compiled in: `date/source/tz.cpp`.  [Here are instructions for doing that.](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation)

> - `boost::posix_time::ptime myTime( boost::gregorian::date(1960, 1, 1))`

This would translate to:

```
auto myTime = date::sys_days{date::year{1960}/1/1};
```

In C++20, everywhere you see `date::` becomes `std::chrono::`.  And if `std::chrono::` scattered everywhere is too irritating for you (it is for me), then a function-local `using namespace std::chrono;` really cleans things up nicely.

The type of `myTime` is `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::ratio<86400>>` (which is why `auto` is such a useful tool here).  In English, that type is a `system_clock::time_point` but with a precision of `days`.  It represents this date in UTC.  You can also think of it as a pointer to the first instant of that date in UTC.  For example if you converted it to a `system_clock::time_point`, then it would point to the midnight where that date begins:

```
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point myTime = date::sys_days{date::year{1960}/1/1};
```

If you are willing to bring `namespace date::literals` into scope you can make this statement slightly more concise:

```
using namespace date::literals;
auto myTime = date::sys_days{1960_y/1/1};
```

> - `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()` and `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()` I guess I could replace this with `high_resolution_clock`. But how can I get the `local_time()` and `universal_time()` equivalents for `std`?

`high_resolution_clock` has no portable mapping to a human calendar.  It does map to the civil calendar on gcc, but not on LLVM or MSVC.  You want to use `system_clock` for this.

"universal time" in C++ is `system_clock`.  Technically `system_clock` is UTC excluding leap seconds, but that is true in boost as well.  If you really want leap seconds, C++20 provides a way to do that (`utc_clock` as opposed to `system_clock`) but this isn't needed as often as you might think.

For universal time at microseconds precision it is:

```
date::sys_time<std::chrono::microseconds> myTime = date::sys_days{1960_y/1/1};
```

Note the reuse of the previous API.  This is a recurring theme in chrono.

For local time you will need `tz.h` and `tz.cpp`.

If you want to specify the time in local time, then simply use `date::local_days` in place of `date::sys_days`:

```
auto myTime = date::local_days{1960_y/1/1};
```

This is a `std::chrono::time_point`, but with a "local clock" which is not associated with a specific time zone (not even your computer's local time zone).  However you *can* associate it with a time zone.  The time zone can then be used to translate between `local_time` and `sys_time`.

The above statement refers to the date 1960-01-01 in *some* local time zone.  Want it in microseconds?  Then:

```
date::local_time<std::chrono::microseconds> myTime = date::local_days{1960_y/1/1};
```

(note recurrent API pattern)

Now let's get a little more interesting.  Let's say you want your computer's local time at 1960-01-01 00:00:00 UTC:

```
auto myTime_utc = date::sys_days{1960_y/1/1};
auto myTime_local = date::current_zone()->to_local(myTime_utc);
```

This looks up your computer's local time zone and uses it to map UTC to your local time.  The precision here will be seconds because in general the UTC offset is in seconds.  If the UTC time had been specified to be microseconds, then the local time would also be microseconds.

```
using namespace std::literals;
using namespace date::literals;

auto myTime_utc = date::sys_days{1960_y/1/1} + 1us;
auto myTime_local = date::current_zone()->to_local(myTime_utc);
```

If you instead wanted to know the UTC time point at 1960-01-01 *local* time then:

```
auto myTime_local = date::local_days{1960_y/1/1};
auto myTime_utc = date::current_zone()->to_sys(myTime_local);
```

And for bonus points, if you want the local time *somewhere else*, that can be done too:

```
auto myTime_utc = date::sys_days{1960_y/1/1};
auto myTime_local = date::locate_zone("Asia/Tokyo")->to_local(myTime_utc);
```

> - `boost::posix_time::time_duration`

This is simply `std::chrono::duration` which is templated on representation and period.  The representation is simply an arithmetic type such as `long long` or `float`.  The period is a `std::ratio<N, D>` where <sup>N</sup>/<sub>D</sub> is the fraction of a second between ticks of the `duration`.  And there exists type aliases for common durations.  For example:

```
using milliseconds = duration<long long, std::ratio<1, 1000>>;
```

Additionally clocks, such as `system_clock` have a "native duration" as a type alias:  `system_clock::duration`.  This is usually set to whatever the underlying OS supplies.  On Apple it is `microseconds`, on linux `nanoseconds` and on Windows 1/10 of `microseconds`.

Example use:

```
auto d = 5ms;
```

`d` has type `std::chrono::milliseconds` and a value of 5.

```
system_clock::duration d = 5ms;
```

Now `d` has type `system_clock::duration` (which varies by platform) and has a value that represents the equivalent of 5 milliseconds.

> - `boost::system_time const timeout = boost::get_system_time()`

This is

```
auto const timeout = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

`timeout` could be used (for example) as an argument in `std::this_thread::sleep_until()`.  Or perhaps more realistically:

```
auto const timeout = std::chrono::system_clock::now() + 3s;
// ...
std::this_thread::sleep_until(timeout);
```

[Here are more boost examples converted to `chrono` / `date`.](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Boost-datetime-Examples-Translated)

### Responses to edit

> 1. I converted boost::system_time const timeout=boost::get_system_time() to auto const timeout = std::chrono::system_clock::now() However this gives me the following errors:

```
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:155:31: error:
```

You will need to migrate to C++11's `std::condition_variable`.  This should be a relatively easy migration.  There is a matching `std::mutex` and `std::unique_lock`.  The `std` version of these tools accept `std::chrono` components for timing as opposed to `boost::chrono` components.  This migration would be even easier if boost would type alias to the std version when available.

> 2. About the conversion from `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()` to `std::chrono::system_clock`... Do i have to use a method contained in `system_clock()`?

`std::chrono::system_clock` has a static member function called `now()`.  And if desired you can store that in a microseconds precision time point:

```
auto tp = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
    std::chrono::system_clock::now());
```

If you don't care what precision it is stored as then simply:

```
auto tp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

> 3. Isn't there any way (even hacky way) to convert these two lines: ...

You could start implementing those parts of C++20 chrono yourself.  Some of it is very simple such as just getting local time points:

```
#include <chrono>

struct local_t {};

template <class Duration>
    using sys_time = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, Duration>;

template <class Duration>
    using local_time = std::chrono::time_point<local_t, Duration>;

auto const UTC_offset = -std::chrono::hours{5};

template <class Duration>
local_time<Duration>
to_local(sys_time<Duration> tp)
{
    return local_time<Duration>{tp.time_since_epoch() + UTC_offset};
}

local_time<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>
local_now()
{
    return to_local(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
}

int
main()
{
    auto tp_local = local_now();
}
```

Formatting `time_point`s gets more challenging.  But it is all implementable in C++11.  Here are [efficient public domain calendrical algorithms](http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html) to get you started.  If you go far enough, you will have re-implemented my [date/time library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) and C++20 chrono.

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer! Your library is great, but unfortunately I am not allowed to use it. I updated the question with some comments based on your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One last thing. Can your local time implementation be done in a more compact manner? Like a one liner or a single function?